# Solve $S= (a+b)^2 -3ab \geqslant 1$ for $a>0$ and $b>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, quadratics

I am trying to solve
$S= (a+b)^2 -3ab \geqslant 1$ for $a>0$ and $b>0$.

After dividing both sides by $ab$, I get $a^2+b^2 \geqslant 2ab$, which means $(a-b)^2  \geqslant 0$ which is always true.

This should also mean that $S=1$ if $a=b$, which, however, does not always hold when I take specific numeric examples. Can anyone tell me why, or where I went wrong?

Comment: What are $a$, $b$? Integers?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: "After dividing both sides by $ab$, I get $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$..." How did you get that from the original inequality? - Looks like that step is wrong.

Comment: Yes, $a^2+b^2+2ab-3ab \geqslant 1$, then divide by $ab$, you get $(a^2+b^2)/ab \geqslant 2$

Comment: The equation $x^2-xy+y^2=1$ is a conic section. The points on our outside this conic section in the 1st quadrant are the solutions to your inequality. There are values in the 1st quadrant inside the interior of the conic (e.g. when both $x$ and $y$ have magnitude less than $1$).

Comment: When you divided both sides by $ab$, you didn't divide the right side.

Answer (score 3):

If $a,b$ are integers, then $$ S = a^2-ab+b^2  = {1\over 2}\Big((a-b)^2+a^2+b^2\Big)\geq {1\over 2}(0+1+1) = 1$$

If they are not, then the statment is not true, take $a=b$ and let $a\to 0$.